# Why was hibernate org.hibernate.classic.Validatable interface deprecated?

Tags: hibernate

I was looking at neat ways of validating my entity before saving it. I came across Validatable interface in earlier versions of Hibernate. Any idea why was this deprecated? And any good alternatives for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has probably been deprecated because there is a standard for bean validation now: [Hibernate Validator](http://www.hibernate.org/subprojects/validator.html), an implementation of the [JSR-303](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=303). It is part of the Java EE 6 standard.

Answer (score 1):

From [migration guide](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/HibernateCoreMigrationGuide30),

> Lifecycle and Validatable interfaces - The Lifecycle and Validatable interfaces were deprecated in Hibernate3 and moved to the org.hibernate.classic package. The Hibernate team does not consider it good practice to have domain model classes depend upon persistence-specific APIs. Hibernate3 applications should use Interceptor or the new Hibernate3 event framework. Existing applications may continue to use Lifecycle and Validatable.

It was removed in [Hibernate 4](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/HibernateCoreMigrationGuide40) . See point 4.